# How to get a single assembly from several C files?

Tags: assembly, merge

I have already build a C project including several source files, and I want to compile those files into `a single assembly`. How can I do that?

GCC just can't help me. I have try two ways, but both failed.

1. When I add the `-S` options in my Makefile, the only result I got is a lot of assembly files.
2. Firstly, I compiled the project and got a ELF file. Then I `deassembly` that ELF file using `dumpobj` tool, finaly I got the assembly file, but there were lots of redundances and was also not match the assembly format.

So, how can I get the single assembly? Does the only way I can do is to combine the source files into one C file?

Comment: If you're using gcc prior to 4.6 you could try `-combine` together with `-S`. This should generate a single assembly file.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using cross toolchain in my Linux and gcc version is 4.1.6

Comment: 4.1.6? The official gcc website shows the 4.1 release series as ending with 4.1.2.  In any case, 4.1.6 is prior to 4.6, so it should still have the `-combine` option.

Comment: I find the -combine option, thanks!

Comment: I'm answering this, because it doesn't seem like anyone will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `-combine` together with `-S` to create a single assembly file.

---

Source: [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524450/michael)